# Using Meteor's Template.rendered for google maps

Tags: google-maps, meteor

I am using the following code:

```
Template.categories.rendered = function() {
  var map = new GMaps({
      div: '#map_canvas',
      lat: -12.043333,
      lng: -77.028333
  });
}
```

to execute the Gmaps.js plugin - and it works, everytime I Submit a form, the layout gets re-rendered and my google maps get a re-paint too.

I also used constant to try to isolate it... And isolate.. Nothing. (it's not inside a template)

```
 {{#constant}}
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
 {{/constant}}
```

I tried changing Template.categories.rendered to Template.categories.created but I got a bunch of errors. I was hoping 'created' only gets executed once..

**edit** I made a new template 'maps' and separated the forms form the map

but I'm afraid this is not a viable solution as I want to communicate between the map and the form.. notably I want to get the latitude and longitude and automatically fill in a field...

Comment: There is an example in Meteor, Parties, which displays a map (openstreetmap) and they also use the `rendered` event and put the map inside a `constant` block so it looks like you're on the right direction. Sorry it does not help much but I suggest you have a look at their example again to see if you can learn something there, or maybe you can migrate to openstreetmap instead of Gmap.

Comment: Thanks, indeed that's an example I should look at as I'm doing a map-based app.. Might be that openstreetmap is a better solution after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting your map in a seperate template e.g

```
<template name="categories">
    {{>map}}
    {{>other_form_with_submit_button}}
</template>
```

So you put your map in the

```
<template name="map">
    <div id="map_canvas></div>
</template>

<template name="other_form_with_submit_button">
    .. your form data
</template>
```

You should still be able to communicate to the map like normal, the DOM doesn't even notice much of the difference

```
Template.other_form_with_submit_button.events({
    'submit' : function() {
        var lat = "-12.043333",
        var lng = "-77.028333";
        var map = new GMaps({
           div: '#map_canvas',
           lat: -12.043333,
           lng: -77.028333
        });
    }
}
```

Similarly while moving the map you can attach a listener and have it change the textbox like you wish:

```
Template.map.rendered = function() {
var map = new GMaps({
      div: '#map_canvas',
      lat: -12.043333,
      lng: -77.028333
});

//Im not sure what you're using to get the location but this is the example if moving the center could be used
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() {
    $("#lat").val(map.getPosition().lat());
    $("#lng").val(map.getPosition().lng());
}

});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed my idea too, but the thing is, I am guessing (I have to test to see) if I got these two in two different templates, and say I want to pan the map when clicking on a list-item on the other template... and I want to use Template.mytemplate.events {} will I have problems? I mean, thinking of it logically, why do we have Template.MyTemplate.events and not simply Template.events if the namespacing is not important?...

Comment: The Template.mytemplate.events only namespaces to make the selectors easier, so as long as the submit button is in the template with the event handler it should be ok, it wont attach to other submit buttons. The google maps functions & event listener attaches directly to the DOM so it isn't aware of the templating system. I used JQuery to change the values of long and lat which also goes directly to the DOM too

Comment: Actually check this: http://vigetlabs.github.com/jmapping/examples/basic.html this is what I want to achieve.. clicking on a url right moves the map and opens the infowindow. I was worried that if the map is in the different template the event handles wont "play" correctly

Comment: You shoudn't really have any trouble doing this the code there should work fine with meteor

Comment: You don't really need anything special with meteor, anything out there  should pretty much work. I know you had a bit of trouble with including scripts but you've figured that all out yeah? Meteor is built well to go well with JQuery plugins or other JS snippets without much hitch

Comment: Your HTML doesn't seem correct, shouldn't the {{}}'s be separately from the <template> declarations?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand? The html seems right, the top {{>map}} loads a <template name="map">..</template> and the bottom is for your form with reactive variables in it

Comment: Yep! As usual, good answer:) Watch out, you should correct "value() to val()" :) I used this: var map = new GMaps({
      div: '#map_canvas',
      lat: -12.043333,
      lng: -77.028333,
      center_changed: function(e) {
    $("#lat").val(map.getCenter().lat());
    $("#lng").val(map.getCenter().lng());    
        }
  }); 
to go with my Gmaps.js plugin:) simpler code:)